Error with the label plotting with seaborn.objects
I am having problems when I want to make a graph about public transport in Argentina, the label is displayed on the graph, what can I do to fix it?
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=60,labelsize=5)
(
  (
    so.Plot()
    .add(so.Line(), data = pasajeros_por_mes, x = "año_mes", y = "cantidad", color = "tipo_transporte")
    .on(ax)
  )
.layout(size=(8,5))
.label(x="Mes y año", y="Cantidad de pasajeros", color = "Tipo de transporte")
.show()
)

I can´t upload images apparently, so this is the problem
Also, if I don´t use the instruction .show the graph is made twice, without the label upon it, but twice, so I have to choose between two graphs, both which look awful
I've tried changing the order of the instructions, investigated here at StackOverflow, searched at https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Plot.layout.html and https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Plot.label.html
But I haven´t found anything that solves this problem

Which seaborn version are you using? Please try to create a reproducible example. Either by starting from one of the demo data sets, or by creating a small test dataframe (3 rows per hue value would be enough in this case).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
